# The difference between "add up" and "lump"

Tags: expressions, differences, vocabulary, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Do these two sentences mean the same thing: "lump all the lodging charges" vs "add up all the lodging charges"? Generally, is the latter used more?

Comment: You can say _lump all the lodging charges_ **together** (consider them as a single group), but, no, _lump_ doesn't mean _add up_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with definitions:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lump)
> *lump*:
> to consider or deal with as a group

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/add)
> *add*:
> to put two or more numbers or amounts together to get a total

Hence we may lump the lodging charges without adding them if, for example, we want to refer to them as a single item (without actually adding the separate charges).

"*The landlord lumps his rental receipts in his tax returns*" would mean he refers to them as a single item of income. The arithmetic detail of the separate amounts is the addition that produces the quantitative measure of the single item.